# how to update a blob column containing XML data in oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, blob

i have tried below two approaches:

1. `update table set blobcolname='<?xml>...';`

got this error: "string literal tool long" - since the xml value that i am inserting is tool long

2.

```
DECLARE
str varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
str:='<?xml>...';
update table set blobcolname = str;
END;
/
```

got this error: ORA-01461:can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Comment: You try to update a `BLOB` with `VARCHAR2` and you get an error related to `LONG`? Something is wrong with your question. Extra-Tip: For XML data you should prefer data type [XMLTYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_xml.htm#ARPLS369)

Comment: Please show us your data type of the column blobcolname ?

Comment: why do you want to store a xml document inserted as plain text in a blob object ? why are you not using in this case clob ?? Blob is for binary objects, you will be storing the xml as binary object if you use blob. If you use CLOB you will store the xml as an string

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the data is already there in DB. cant do any modification with datatype. just need to update it. The datatype of the column in table is shown as 'BLOB'

Comment: @VBoka its 'BLOB'

Comment: @RobertoHernandez the data is already there in DB. Cant change datatype. Just need to update it.

Comment: @setianea, can you create a function in your database ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an option to install two functions in your database, I would use this:

First: I create a function to convert a clob to a blob object

```
create or replace function clob_to_blob (p1_clob CLOB) return BLOB is
  Result BLOB;
  o1 integer;
  o2 integer;
  c integer;
  w integer;
begin
  o1 := 1;
  o2 := 1;
  c := 0;
  w := 0;
  DBMS_LOB.CreateTemporary(Result, true);
  DBMS_LOB.ConvertToBlob(Result, p1_clob, length(p1_clob), o1, o2, 0, c, w);
  return(Result);
end clob2blob;
/
```

Second: I create a function to the opposite, convert a blob to a clob

```
create or replace function blob_to_char (p1_blob BLOB)
return clob is
  out_clob clob;
  n number;
begin
  if (p1_blob is null) then
    return null;
  end if;
  if (length(p1_blob)=0) then
    return empty_clob();
  end if;
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(out_clob,true);
  n:=1;
  while (n+32767<=length(p1_blob)) loop
    dbms_lob.writeappend(out_clob,32767,utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(p1_blob,32767,n)));
    n:=n+32767;
  end loop;
  dbms_lob.writeappend(out_clob,length(p1_blob)-n+1,utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(p1_blob,length(p1_blob)-n+1,n)));
  return out_clob;
end;
/
```

Third: To verify that I can insert

```
declare
str clob;
BEGIN
str :='<?xml>...';
update table set blobcolname = clob_to_blob ( str );
END;
/
```

Lastly: To make a regression test and check that I got the xml as it was originally

```
select blob_to_char( blobcolname ) from your table;
```

Comment: if you find the answer valid, may you accept it ? It will help other users